# SQL Server - Cant connect to instance with either windows auth or SA account

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have just installed SQL Server 2012 and I cannot connect to the new instance using any method.

The instance is MSSQLServer

I have attempted \MSSQLSERVER, .\MSSQLSERVER, localhost\MSSQLSERVER and 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER using both windows authentication and the sa account.

I set the SA account's password when installing SQL.

I am at a complete loss as to how I should proceed. Can anyone advise?

**Edit**

I should mention, I am getting the error codes SQL Network Interface, error : 25 - Connection string not valid and Microsoft SQL Server, error: 87

**Double Edit**

I also opened up port 1433 on my firewall in both directions, though i am not trying to do this remotely.

Comment: If you're local, open up SSMS and just type in the name of the server... MSSQLSERVER means it's the default instance and that doesn't need to be added anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed default instance. Hence you shouldn't mention MSSQLSERVER.

You can connect SQL Server using only `localhost` or `.\`.